# Limit to path name on ext4 file system

Tags: linux, bash, ext4

Though it is mentioned that there is no limit to length of path name but below command does not work for a path which is **48923** characters long, may be because of some limitation in bash or cd command

I had to trim the output since body limit is 30000 here.

```
[root@localhost LV1]# cd /DeepDirectoryStructure094107/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16/17/18/19/20/21/22/23/24/25/26/27/28/29/30/31/32/33..../7620/7621/7622/7623/7624/7625/7626/7627/7628/7629/7630/7631/7632/7633/7634/7635/7636/7637/7638/7639/7640/7641/7642/7643/7644/7645/7646/7647/7648/7649/7650/7651/7652/7653/7654/7655/7656/7657/7658/7659/7660/7661/7662/7663/7664/7665/7666/7667/7668/7669/7670/7671/7672/7673/7674/7675/7676/7677/7678/7679/7680/7681/7682/7683/7684/7685/7686/7687/7688/7689/7690/7691/7692/7693/7694/7695/7696/7697/7698/7699/7700/7701/7702/7703/7704/7705/7706/7707/7708/7709/7710/7711/7712/7713/7714/7715/7716/7717/7718/7719/7720/7721/7722/7723/7724/7725/7726/7727/7728/7729/7730/7731/7732/7733/7734/7735/7736/7737/7738/7739/7740/7741/7742/7743/7744/7745/7746/7747/7748/7749/7750/7751/7752/7753/7754/7755/7756/7757/7758/7759/7760/7761/7762/7763/7764/7765/7766/7767/7768/7769/7770/7771/7772/7773/7774/7775/7776/7777/7778/7779/7780/7781/7782/7783/7784/7785/7786/7787/7788/7789/7790/7791/7792/7793/7794/7795/7796/7797/7798/7799/7800/7801/7802/7803/7804/7805/7806/7807/7808/7809/7810/7811/7812/7813/7814/7815/7816/7817/7818/7819/7820/7821/7822/7823/7824/7825/7826/7827/7828/7829/7830/7831/7832/7833/7834/7835/7836/7837/7838/7839/7840/7841/7842/7843/7844/7845/7846/7847/7848/7849/7850/7851/7852/7853/7854/7855/7856/7857/7858/7859/7860/7861/7862/7863/7864/7865/7866/7867/7868/7869/7870/7871/7872/7873/7874/7875/7876/7877/7878/7879/7880/7881/7882/7883/7884/7885/7886/7887/7888/7889/7890/7891/7892/7893/7894/7895/7896/7897/7898/7899/7900/7901/7902/7903/7904/7905/7906/7907/7908/7909/7910/7911/7912/7913/7914/7915/7916/7917/7918/7919/7920/7921/7922/7923/7924/7925/7926/7927/7928/7929/7930/7931/7932/7933/7934/7935/7936/7937/7938/7939/7940/7941/7942/7943/7944/7945/7946/7947/7948/7949/7950/7951/7952/7953/7954/7955/7956/7957/7958/7959/7960/7961/7962/7963/7964/7965/7966/7967/7968/7969/7970/7971/7972/7973/7974/7975/7976/7977/7978/7979/7980/7981/7982/7983/7984/7985/7986/7987/7988/7989/7990/7991/7992/7993/7994/7995/7996/7997/7998/7999/8000/8001/8002/8003/8004/8005/8006/8007/8008/8009/8010/8011/8012/8013/8014/8015/8016/8017/8018/8019/8020/8021/8022/8023/8024/8025/8026/8027/8028/8029/8030/8031/8032/8033/8034/8035/8036/8037/8038/8039/8040/8041/8042/8043/8044/8045/8046/8047/8048/8049/8050/8051/8052/8053/8054/8055/8056/8057/8058/8059/8060/8061/8062/8063/8064/8065/8066/8067/8068/8069/8070/8071/8072/8073/8074/8075/8076/8077/8078/8079/8080/8081/8082/8083/8084/8085/8086/8087/8088/8089/8090/8091/8092/8093/8094/8095/8096/8097/8098/8099/8100/8101/8102/8103/8104/8105/8106/8107/8108/8109/8110/8111/8112/8113/8114/8115/8116/8117/8118/8119/8120/8121/8122/8123/8124/8125/8126/8127/8128/8129/8130/8131/8132/8133/8134/8135/8136/8137/8138/8139/8140/8141/8142/8143/8144/8145/8146/8147/8148/8149/8150/8151/8152/8153/8154/8155/8156/8157/8158/8159/8160/8161/8162/8163/8164/8165/8166/8167/8168/8169/8170/8171/8172/8173/8174/8175/8176/8177/8178/8179/8180/8181/8182/8183/8184/8185/8186/8187/8188/8189/8190/8191/8192/8193/8194/8195/8196/8197/8198/8199/8200/8201/8202/8203/8204/8205/8206/8207/8208/8209/8210/8211/8212/8213/8214/8215/8216/8217/8218/8219/8220/8221/8222/8223/8224/8225/8226/8227/8228/8229/8230/8231/8232/8233/8234/8235/8236/8237/8238/8239/8240/8241/8242/8243/8244/8245/8246/8247/8248/8249/8250/8251/8252/8253/8254/8255/8256/8257/8258/8259/8260/8261/8262/8263/8264/8265/8266/8267/8268/8269/8270/8271/8272/8273/8274/8275/8276/8277/8278/8279/8280/8281/8282/8283/8284/8285/8286/8287/8288/8289/8290/8291/8292/8293/8294/8295/8296/8297/8298/8299/8300/8301/8302/8303/8304/8305/8306/8307/8308/8309/8310/8311/8312/8313/8314/8315/8316/8317/8318/8319/8320/8321/8322/8323/8324/8325/8326/8327/8328/8329/8330/8331/8332/8333/8334/8335/8336/8337/8338/8339/8340/8341/8342/8343/8344/8345/8346/8347/8348/8349/8350/8351/8352/8353/8354/8355/8356/8357/8358/8359/8360/8361/8362/8363/8364/8365/8366/8367/8368/8369/8370/8371/8372/8373/8374/8375/8376/8377/8378/8379/8380/8381/8382/8383/8384/8385/8386/8387/8388/8389/8390/8391/8392/8393/8394/8395/8396/8397/8398/8399/8400/8401/8402/8403/8404/8405/8406/8407/8408/8409/8410/8411/8412/8413/8414/8415/8416/8417/8418/8419/8420/8421/8422/8423/8424/8425/8426/8427/8428/8429/8430/8431/8432/8433/8434/8435/8436/8437/8438/8439/8440/8441/8442/8443/8444/8445/8446/8447/8448/8449/8450/8451/8452/8453/8454/8455/8456/8457/8458/8459/8460/8461/8462/8463/8464/8465/8466/8467/8468/8469/8470/8471/8472/8473/8474/8475/8476/8477/8478/8479/8480/8481/8482/8483/8484/8485/8486/8487/8488/8489/8490/8491/8492/8493/8494/8495/8496/8497/8498/8499/8500/8501/8502/8503/8504/8505/8506/8507/8508/8509/8510/8511/8512/8513/8514/8515/8516/8517/8518/8519/8520/8521/8522/8523/8524/8525/8526/8527/8528/8529/8530/8531/8532/8533/8534/8535/8536/8537/8538/8539/8540/8541/8542/8543/8544/8545/8546/8547/8548/8549/8550/8551/8552/8553/8554/8555/8556/8557/8558/8559/8560/8561/8562/8563/8564/8565/8566/8567/8568/8569/8570/8571/8572/8573/8574/8575/8576/8577/8578/8579/8580/8581/8582/8583/8584/8585/8586/8587/8588/8589/8590/8591/8592/8593/8594/8595/8596/8597/8598/8599/8600/8601/8602/8603/8604/8605/8606/8607/8608/8609/8610/8611/8612/8613/8614/8615/8616/8617/8618/8619/8620/8621/8622/8623/8624/8625/8626/8627/8628/8629/8630/8631/8632/8633/8634/8635/8636/8637/8638/8639/8640/8641/8642/8643/8644/8645/8646/8647/8648/8649/8650/8651/8652/8653/8654/8655/8656/8657/8658/8659/8660/8661/8662/8663/8664/8665/8666/8667/8668/8669/8670/8671/8672/8673/8674/8675/8676/8677/8678/8679/8680/8681/8682/8683/8684/8685/8686/8687/8688/8689/8690/8691/8692/8693/8694/8695/8696/8697/8698/8699/8700/8701/8702/8703/8704/8705/8706/8707/8708/8709/8710/8711/8712/8713/8714/8715/8716/8717/8718/8719/8720/8721/8722/8723/8724/8725/8726/8727/8728/8729/8730/8731/8732/8733/8734/8735/8736/8737/8738/8739/8740/8741/8742/8743/8744/8745/8746/8747/8748/8749/8750/8751/8752/8753/8754/8755/8756/8757/8758/8759/8760/8761/8762/8763/8764/8765/8766/8767/8768/8769/8770/8771/8772/8773/8774/8775/8776/8777/8778/8779/8780/8781/8782/8783/8784/8785/8786/8787/8788/8789/8790/8791/8792/8793/8794/8795/8796/8797/8798/8799/8800/8801/8802/8803/8804/8805/8806/8807/8808/8809/8810/8811/8812/8813/8814/8815/8816/8817/8818/8819/8820/8821/8822/8823/8824/8825/8826/8827/8828/8829/8830/8831/8832/8833/8834/8835/8836/8837/8838/8839/8840/8841/8842/8843/8844/8845/8846/8847/8848/8849/8850/8851/8852/8853/8854/8855/8856/8857/8858/8859/8860/8861/8862/8863/8864/8865/8866/8867/8868/8869/8870/8871/8872/8873/8874/8875/8876/8877/8878/8879/8880/8881/8882/8883/8884/8885/8886/8887/8888/8889/8890/8891/8892/8893/8894/8895/8896/8897/8898/8899/8900/8901/8902/8903/8904/8905/8906/8907/8908/8909/8910/8911/8912/8913/8914/8915/8916/8917/8918/8919/8920/8921/8922/8923/8924/8925/8926/8927/8928/8929/8930/8931/8932/8933/8934/8935/8936/8937/8938/8939/8940/8941/8942/8943/8944/8945/8946/8947/8948/8949/8950/8951/8952/8953/8954/8955/8956/8957/8958/8959/8960/8961/8962/8963/8964/8965/8966/8967/8968/8969/8970/8971/8972/8973/8974/8975/8976/8977/8978/8979/8980/8981/8982/8983/8984/8985/8986/8987/8988/8989/8990/8991/8992/8993/8994/8995/8996/8997/8998/8999/9000/9001/9002/9003/9004/9005/9006/9007/9008/9009/9010/9011/9012/9013/9014/9015/9016/9017/9018/9019/9020/9021/9022/9023/9024/9025/9026/9027/9028/9029/9030/9031/9032/9033/9034/9035/9036/9037/9038/9039/9040/9041/9042/9043/9044/9045/9046/9047/9048/9049/9050/9051/9052/9053/9054/9055/9056/9057/9058/9059/9060/9061/9062/9063/9064/9065/9066/9067/9068/9069/9070/9071/9072/9073/9074/9075/9076/9077/9078/9079/9080/9081/9082/9083/9084/9085/9086/9087/9088/9089/9090/9091/9092/9093/9094/9095/9096/9097/9098/9099/9100/9101/9102/9103/9104/9105/9106/9107/9108/9109/9110/9111/9112/9113/9114/9115/9116/9117/9118/9119/9120/9121/9122/9123/9124/9125/9126/9127/9128/9129/9130/9131/9132/9133/9134/9135/9136/9137/9138/9139/9140/9141/9142/9143/9144/9145/9146/9147/9148/9149/9150/9151/9152/9153/9154/9155/9156/9157/9158/9159/9160/9161/9162/9163/9164/9165/9166/9167/9168/9169/9170/9171/9172/9173/9174/9175/9176/9177/9178/9179/9180/9181/9182/9183/9184/9185/9186/9187/9188/9189/9190/9191/9192/9193/9194/9195/9196/9197/9198/9199/9200/9201/9202/9203/9204/9205/9206/9207/9208/9209/9210/9211/9212/9213/9214/9215/9216/9217/9218/9219/9220/9221/9222/9223/9224/9225/9226/9227/9228/9229/9230/9231/9232/9233/9234/9235/9236/9237/9238/9239/9240/9241/9242/9243/9244/9245/9246/9247/9248/9249/9250/9251/9252/9253/9254/9255/9256/9257/9258/9259/9260/9261/9262/9263/9264/9265/9266/9267/9268/9269/9270/9271/9272/9273/9274/9275/9276/9277/9278/9279/9280/9281/9282/9283/9284/9285/9286/9287/9288/9289/9290/9291/9292/9293/9294/9295/9296/9297/9298/9299/9300/9301/9302/9303/9304/9305/9306/9307/9308/9309/9310/9311/9312/9313/9314/9315/9316/9317/9318/9319/9320/9321/9322/9323/9324/9325/9326/9327/9328/9329/9330/9331/9332/9333/9334/9335/9336/9337/9338/9339/9340/9341/9342/9343/9344/9345/9346/9347/9348/9349/9350/9351/9352/9353/9354/9355/9356/9357/9358/9359/9360/9361/9362/9363/9364/9365/9366/9367/9368/9369/9370/9371/9372/9373/9374/9375/9376/9377/9378/9379/9380/9381/9382/9383/9384/9385/9386/9387/9388/9389/9390/9391/9392/9393/9394/9395/9396/9397/9398/9399/9400/9401/9402/9403/9404/9405/9406/9407/9408/9409/9410/9411/9412/9413/9414/9415/9416/9417/9418/9419/9420/9421/9422/9423/9424/9425/9426/9427/9428/9429/9430/9431/9432/9433/9434/9435/9436/9437/9438/9439/9440/9441/9442/9443/9444/9445/9446/9447/9448/9449/9450/9451/9452/9453/9454/9455/9456/9457/9458/9459/9460/9461/9462/9463/9464/9465/9466/9467/9468/9469/9470/9471/9472/9473/9474/9475/9476/9477/9478/9479/9480/9481/9482/9483/9484/9485/9486/9487/9488/9489/9490/9491/9492/9493/9494/9495/9496/9497/9498/9499/9500/9501/9502/9503/9504/9505/9506/9507/9508/9509/9510/9511/9512/9513/9514/9515/9516/9517/9518/9519/9520/9521/9522/9523/9524/9525/9526/9527/9528/9529/9530/9531/9532/9533/9534/9535/9536/9537/9538/9539/9540/9541/9542/9543/9544/9545/9546/9547/9548/9549/9550/9551/9552/9553/9554/9555/9556/9557/9558/9559/9560/9561/9562/9563/9564/9565/9566/9567/9568/9569/9570/9571/9572/9573/9574/9575/9576/9577/9578/9579/9580/9581/9582/9583/9584/9585/9586/9587/9588/9589/9590/9591/9592/9593/9594/9595/9596/9597/9598/9599/9600/9601/9602/9603/9604/9605/9606/9607/9608/9609/9610/9611/9612/9613/9614/9615/9616/9617/9618/9619/9620/9621/9622/9623/9624/9625/9626/9627/9628/9629/9630/9631/9632/9633/9634/9635/9636/9637/9638/9639/9640/9641/9642/9643/9644/9645/9646/9647/9648/9649/9650/9651/9652/9653/9654/9655/9656/9657/9658/9659/9660/9661/9662/9663/9664/9665/9666/9667/9668/9669/9670/9671/9672/9673/9674/9675/9676/9677/9678/9679/9680/9681/9682/9683/9684/9685/9686/9687/9688/9689/9690/9691/9692/9693/9694/9695/9696/9697/9698/9699/9700/9701/9702/9703/9704/9705/9706/9707/9708/9709/9710/9711/9712/9713/9714/9715/9716/9717/9718/9719/9720/9721/9722/9723/9724/9725/9726/9727/9728/9729/9730/9731/9732/9733/9734/9735/9736/9737/9738/9739/9740/9741/9742/9743/9744/9745/9746/9747/9748/9749/9750/9751/9752/9753/9754/9755/9756/9757/9758/9759/9760/9761/9762/9763/9764/9765/9766/9767/9768/9769/9770/9771/9772/9773/9774/9775/9776/9777/9778/9779/9780/9781/9782/9783/9784/9785/9786/9787/9788/9789/9790/9791/9792/9793/9794/9795/9796/9797/9798/9799/9800/9801/9802/9803/9804/9805/9806/9807/9808/9809/9810/9811/9812/9813/9814/9815/9816/9817/9818/9819/9820/9821/9822/9823/9824/9825/9826/9827/9828/9829/9830/9831/9832/9833/9834/9835/9836/9837/9838/9839/9840/9841/9842/9843/9844/9845/9846/9847/9848/9849/9850/9851/9852/9853/9854/9855/9856/9857/9858/9859/9860/9861/9862/9863/9864/9865/9866/9867/9868/9869/9870/9871/9872/9873/9874/9875/9876/9877/9878/9879/9880/9881/9882/9883/9884/9885/9886/9887/9888/9889/9890/9891/9892/9893/9894/9895/9896/9897/9898/9899/9900/9901/9902/9903/9904/9905/9906/9907/9908/9909/9910/9911/9912/9913/9914/9915/9916/9917/9918/9919/9920/9921/9922/9923/9924/9925/9926/9927/9928/9929/9930/9931/9932/9933/9934/9935/9936/9937/9938/9939/9940/9941/9942/9943/9944/9945/9946/9947/9948/9949/9950/9951/9952/9953/9954/9955/9956/9957/9958/9959/9960/9961/9962/9963/9964/9965/9966/9967/9968/9969/9970/9971/9972/9973/9974/9975/9976/9977/9978/9979/9980/9981/9982/9983/9984/9985/9986/9987/9988/9989/9990/9991/9992/9993/9994/9995/9996/9997/9998/9999/10000/


-bash: cd: /DeepDirectoryStructure094107/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16/17/18/19/20/21/22/23/24/25/26/27/28/29/30/31/32/33/34/35/36/37/38/39/40/41/42/43/44/45/46/47/48/49/50/51/52/53/54/55/56/57/58/59/60/61/62/63/64/65/66/67/68/69/70/71/72/73/74/75/76/77/78/79/80/81/82/83/84/85/86/87/88/89/90/91/92/93/94/95/96/97/98/99/100/101/102/103/104/105/106/107/108/109/110/111/112/113/114/115/116/117/118/119/120/121/122/123/124/125/126/127/128/129/130/131/132/133/134/135/136/137/138/139/140/141/142/143/144/145/146/147/148/149/150/151/152/153/154/155/156/157/158/159/160/161/162/163/164/165/166/167/168/169/170/171/172/173/174/175/176/177/178/179/180/181/182/183/184/185/186/187/188/189/190/191/192/193/194/195/196/197/198/199/200/201/202/203/204/205/206/207/208/209/210/211/212/213/214/215/216/217/218/219/220/221/222/223/224/225/226/227/228/229/230/231/232/233/234/235/236/237/238/239/240/241/242/243/244/245/246/247/248/249/250/251/252/253/254/255/256/257/258/259/260/261/262/263/264/265/266/267/268/269/270/271/272/273/274/275/276/277/278/279/280/281/282/283/284/285/286/287/288/289/290/291/292/293/294/295/296/297/298/299/300/301/302/303/304/305/306/307/308/309/310/311/312/313/314/315/316/317/318/319/320/321/322/323/324/325/326/327/328/329/330/331/332/333/334/335/336/337/338/339/340/341/342/343/344/345/346/347/348/349/350/351/352/353/354/355/356/357/358/359/360/361/362/363/364/365/366/367/368/369/370/371/372/373/374/375/376/377/378/379/380/381/382/383/384/385/386/387/388/389/390/391/392/393/394/395/396/397/398/399/400/401/402/403/404/405/406/407/408/409/410/411/412/413/414/415/416/417/418/419/420/421/422/423/424/425/426/427/428/429/430/431/432/433/434/435/436/437/438/439/440/441/442/443/444/445/446/447/448/449/450/451/452/453/454/455/456/457/458/459/460/461/462/463/464/465/466/467/468/469/470/471/472/473/474/475/476/477/478/479/480/481/482/483/484/485/486/487/488/489/490/491/492/493/494/495/496/497/498/499/500/501/502/503/504/505/506/507/508/509/510/511/512/513/514/515/516/517/518/519/520/521/522/523/524/525/526/527/528/529/530/531/532/533/534/535/536/537/538/539/540/541/542/543/544/545/546/547/548/549/550/551/552/553/554/555/556/557/558/559/560/561/562/563/564/565/566/567/568/569/570/571/572/573/574/575/576/577/578/579/580/581/582/583/584/585/586/587/588/589/590/591/592/593/594/595/596/597/598/599/600/601/602/603/604/605/606/607/608/609/610/611/612/613/614/615/616/617/618/619/620/621/622/623/624/625/626/627/628/629/630/631/632/633/634/635/636/637/638/639/640/641/642/643/644/645/646/647/648/649/650/651/652/653/654/655/656/657/658/659/660/661/662/663/664/665/666/667/668/669/670/671/672/673/674/675/676/677/678/679/680/681/682/683/684/685/686/687/688/689/690/691/692/693/694/695/696/697/698/699/700/701/702/703/704/705/706/707/708/709/710/711/712/713/714/715/716/717/718/719/720/721/722/723/724/725/726/727/728/729/730/731/732/733/734/735/736/737/738/739/740/741/742/743/744/745/746/747/748/749/750/751/752/753/754/755/756/757/758/759/760/761/762/763/764/765/766/767/768/769/770/771/772/773/774/775/776/777/778/779/780/781/782/783/784/785/786/787/788/789/790/791/792/793/794/795/796/797/798/799/800/801/802/803/804/805/806/807/808/809/810/811/812/813/814/815/816/817/818/819/820/821/822/823/824/825/826/827/828/829/830/831/832/833/834/835/836/837/838/839/840/841/842/843/844/845/846/847/848/849/850/851/852/853/854/855/856/857/858/859/860/861/862/863/864/865/866/867/868/869/870/871/872/873/874/875/876/877/878/879/880/881/882/883/884/885/886/887/888/889/890/891/892/893/894/895/896/897/898/899/900/901/902/903/904/905/906/907/908/909/910/911/912/913/914/915/916/917/918/919/920/921/922/923/924/925/926/927/928/929/930/931/932/933/934/935/936/937/938/939/940/941/942/943/944/945/946/947/948/949/950/951/952/953/954/955/956/957/958/959/960/961/962/963/964/965/966/967/968/969/970/971/972/973/974/975/976/977/978/979/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987/988/989/990/991/992/993/994/995/996/997/998/999/1000/1001/1002/1003/1004/1005/1006/1007/1008/1009/1010/1011/1012/1013/1014/1015/1016/1017/1018/1019/1020/1021/1022/1023/1024/1025/1026/1027/1028/1029/1030/1031/1032/1033/1034/1035/1036/1037/1038/1039/1040/1041/1042/1043/1044/1045/1046/1047/1048/1049/1050/1051/1052/1053/1054/1055/1056/1057/1058/1059/1060/1061/1062/1063/1064/1065/1066/1067/1068/1069/1070/1071/1072/1073/1074/1075/1076/1077/1078/1079/1080/1081/1082/1083/1084/1085/1086/1087/1088/1089/1090/1091/1092/1093/1094/1095/1096/1097/1098/1099/1100/1101/1102/1103/1104/1105/1106/1107/1108/1109/1110/1111/1112/1113/1114/1115/1116/1117/1118/1119/1120/1121/1122/1123/1124/1125/1126/1127/1128/1129/1130/1131/1132/1133/1134/1135/1136/1137/1138/1139/1140/1141/1142/1143/1144/1145/1146/1147/1148/1149/1150/1151/1152/1153/1154/1155/1156/1157/1158/1159/1160/1161/1162/1163/1164/1165/1166/1167/1168/1169/1170/1171/1172/1173/1174/1175/1176/1177/1178/1179/1180/1181/1182/1183/1184/1185/1186/1187/1188/1189/1190/1191/1192/1193/1194/1195/1196/1197/1198/1199/1200/1201/1202/1203/1204/1205/1206/1207/1208/1209/1210/1211/1212/1213/1214/1215/1216/1217/1218/1219/1220/1221/1222/1223/1224/1225/1226/1227/1228/1229/1230/1231/1232/1233/1234/1235/1236/1237/1238/1239/1240/1241/1242/1243/1244/1245/1246/1247/1248/1249/1250/1251/1252/1253/1254/1255/1256/1257/1258/1259/1260/1261/1262/1263/1264/1265/1266/1267/1268/1269/1270/1271/1272/1273/1274/1275/1276/1277/1278/1279/1280/1281/1282/1283/1284/1285/1286/1287/1288/1289/1290/1291/1292/1293/1294/1295/1296/1297/1298/1299/1300/1301/1302/1303/1304/1305/1306/1307/1308/1309/1310/1311/1312/1313/1314/1315/1316/1317/1318/1319/1320/1321/1322/1323/1324/1325/1326/1327/1328/1329/1330/1331/1332/1333/1334/1335/1336/1337/1338/1339/1340/1341/1342/1343/1344/1345/1346/1347/1348/1349/1350/1351/1352/1353/1354/1355/1356/1357/1358/1359/1360/1361/1362/1363/1364/1365/1366/1367/1368/1369/1370/1371/1372/1373/1374/1375/1376/1377/1378/1379/1380/1381/1382/1383/1384/1385/1386/1387/1388/1389/1390/1391/1392/1393/1394/1395/1396/1397/1398/1399/1400/1401/1402/1403/1404/1405/1406/1407/1408/1409/1410/1411/1412/1413/1414/1415/1416/1417/1418/1419/1420/1421/1422/1423/1424/1425/1426/1427/1428/1429/1430/1431/1432/1433/1434/1435/1436/1437/1438/1439/1440/1441/1442/1443/1444/1445/1446/1447/1448/1449/1450/1451/1452/1453/1454/1455/1456/1457/1458/1459/1460/1461/1462/1463/1464/1465/1466/1467/1468/1469/1470/1471/1472/1473/1474/1475/1476/1477/1478/1479/1480/1481/1482/1483/1484/1485/1486/1487/1488/1489/1490/1491/1492/1493/1494/1495/1496/1497/1498/1499/1500/1501/1502/1503/1504/1505/1506/1507/1508/1509/1510/1511/1512/1513/1514/1515/1516/1517/1518/1519/1520/1521/1522/1523/1524/1525/1526/1527/1528/1529/1530/1531/1532/1533/1534/1535/1536/1537/1538/1539/1540/1541/1542/1543/1544/1545/1546/1547/1548/1549/1550/1551/1552/1553/1554/1555/1556/1557/1558/1559/1560/1561/1562/1563/1564/1565/1566/1567/1568/1569/1570/1571/1572/1573/1574/1575/1576/1577/1578/1579/1580/1581/1582/1583/1584/1585/1586/1587/1588/1589/1590/1591/1592/1593/1594/1595/1596/1597/1598/1599/1600/1601/1602/1603/1604/1605/1606/1607/1608/1609/1610/1611/1612/1613/1614/1615/1616/1617/1618/1619/1620/1621/1622/1623/1624/1625/1626/1627/1628/1629/1630/1631/1632/1633/1634/1635/1636/1637/1638/1639/1640/1641/1642/1643/1644/1645/1646/1647/1648/1649/1650/1651/1652/1653/1654/1655/1656/1657/1658/1659/1660/1661/1662/1663/1664/1665/1666/1667/1668/1669/1670/1671/1672/1673/1674/1675/1676/1677/1678/1679/1680/1681/1682/1683/1684/1685/1686/1687/1688/1689/1690/1691/1692/1693/1694/1695/1696/1697/1698/1699/1700/1701/1702/1703/1704/1705/1706/1707/1708/1709/1710/1711/1712/1713/1714/1715/1716/1717/1718/1719/1720/1721/1722/1723/1724/1725/1726/1727/1728/1729/1730/1731/1732/1733/1734/1735/1736/1737/1738/1739/1740/1741/1742/1743/1744/1745/1746/1747/1748/1749/1750/1751/1752/1753/1754/1755/1756/1757/1758/1759/1760/1761/1762/1763/1764/1765/1766/1767/1768/1769/1770/1771/1772/1773/1774/1775/1776/1777/1778/1779/1780/1781/1782/1783/1784/1785/1786/1787/1788/1789/1790/1791/1792/1793/1794/1795/1796/1797/1798/1799/1800/1801/1802/1803/1804/1805/1806/1807/1808/1809/1810/1811/1812/1813/1814/1815/1816/1817/1818/1819/1820/1821/1822/1823/1824/1825/1826/1827/1828/1829/1830/1831/1832/1833/1834/1835/1836/1837/1838/1839/1840/1841/1842/1843/1844/1845/1846/1847/1848/1849/1850/1851/1852/1853/1854/1855/1856/1857/1858/1859/1860/1861/1862/1863/1864/1865/1866/1867/1868/1869/1870/1871/1872/1873/1874/1875/1876/1877/1878/1879/1880/1881/1882/1883/1884/1885/1886/1887/1888/1889/1890/1891/1892/1893/1894/1895/1896/1897/1898/1899/1900/1901/1902/1903/1904/1905/1906/1907/1908/1909/1910/1911/1912/1913/1914/1915/1916/1917/1918/1919/1920/1921/1922/1923/1924/1925/1926/1927/1928/1929/1930/1931/1932/1933/1934/1935/1936/1937/1938/1939/1940/1941/1942/1943/1944/1945/1946/1947/1948/1949/1950/1951/1952/1953/1954/1955/1956/1957/1958/1959/1960/1961/1962/1963/1964/1965/1966/1967/1968/1969/1970/1971/1972/1973/1974/1975/1976/1977/1978/1979/1980/1981/1982/1983/1984/1985/1986/1987/1988/1989/1990/1991/1992/1993/1994/1995/1996/1997/1998/1999/2000/2001/2002/2003/2004/2005/2006/2007/2008/2009/2010/2011/2012/2013/2014/2015/2016/2017/2018/2019/2020/2021/2022/2023/2024/2025/2026/2027/2028/2029/2030/2031/2032/2033/2034/2035/2036/2037/2038/2039/2040/2041/2042/2043/2044/2045/2046/2047/2048/2049/2050/2051/2052/2053/2054/2055/2056/2057/2058/2059/2060/2061/2062/2063/2064/2065/2066/2067/2068/2069/2070/2071/2072/2073/2074/2075/2076/2077/2078/2079/2080/2081/2082/2083/2084/2085/2086/2087/2088/2089/2090/2091/2092/2093/2094/2095/2096/2097/2098/2099/2100/2101/2102/2103/2104/2105/2106/2107/2108/2109/2110/2111/2112/2113/2114/2115/2116/2117/2118/2119/2120/2121/2122/2123/2124/2125/2126/2127/2128/2129/2130/2131/2132/2133/2134/2135/2136/2137/2138/2139/2140/2141/2142/2143/2144/2145/2146/2147/2148/2149/2150/2151/2152/2153/2154/2155/2156/2157/2158/2159/2160/2161/2162/2163/2164/2165/2166/2167/2168/2169/2170/2171/2172/2173/2174/2175/2176/2177/2178/2179/2180/2181/2182/2183/2184/2185/2186/2187/2188/2189/2190/2191/2192/2193/2194/2195/2196/2197/2198/2199/2200/2201/2202/2203/2204/2205/2206/2207/2208/2209/2210/2211/2212/2213/2214/2215/2216/2217/2218/2219/2220/2221/2222/2223/2224/2225/2226/2227/2228/2229/2230/2231/2232/2233/2234/2235/2236/2237/2238/2239/2240/2241/2242/2243/2244/2245/2246/2247/2248/2249/2250/2251/2252/2253/2254/2255/2256/2257/2258/2259/2260/2261/2262/2263/2264/2265/2266/2267/2268/2269/2270/2271/2272/2273/2274/2275/2276/2277/2278/2279/2280/2281/2282/2283/2284/2285/2286/2287/2288/2289/2290/2291/2292/2293/2294/2295/2296/2297/2298/2299/2300/2301/2302/2303/2304/2305/2306/2307/2308/2309/2310/2311/2312/2313/2314/2315/2316/2317/2318/2319/2320/2321/2322/2323/2324/2325/2326/2327/2328/2329/2330/2331/2332/2333/2334/2335/2336/2337/2338/2339/2340/2341/2342/2343/2344/2345/2346/2347/2348/2349/2350/2351/2352/2353/2354/2355/2356/2357/2358/2359/2360/2361/2362/2363/2364/2365/2366/2367/2368/2369/2370/2371/2372/2373/2374/2375/2376/2377/2378/2379/2380/2381/2382/2383/2384/2385/2386/2387/2388/2389/2390/2391/2392/2393/2394/2395/2396/2397/2398/2399/2400/2401/2402/2403/2404/2405/2406/2407/2408/2409/2410/2411/2412/2413/2414/2415/2416/2417/2418/2419/2420/2421/2422/2423/2424/2425/2426/2427/2428/2429/2430/2431/2432/2433/2434/2435/2436/2437/2438/2439/2440/2441/2442/2443/2444/2445/2446/2447/2448/2449/2450/2451/2452/2453/2454/2455/2456/2457/2458/2459/2460/2461/2462/2463/2464/2465/2466/2467/2468/2469/2470/2471/2472/2473/2474/2475/2476/2477/2478/2479/2480/2481/2482/2483/2484/2485/2486/2487/2488/2489/2490/2491/2492/2493/2494/2495/2496/2497/2498/2499/2500/2501/2502/2503/2504/2505/2506/2507/2508/2509/2510/2511/2512/2513/2514/2515/2516/2517/2518/2519/2520/2521/2522/2523/2524/2525/2526/2527/2528/2529/2530/2531/2532/2533/2534/2535/2536/2537/2538/2539/2540/2541/2542/2543/2544/2545/2546/2547/2548/2549/2550/2551/2552/2553/2554/2555/2556/2557/2558/2559/2560/2561/2562/2563/2564/2565/2566/2567/2568/2569/2570/2571/2572/2573/2574/2575/2576/2577/2578/2579/2580/2581/2582/2583/2584/2585/2586/2587/2588/2589/2590/2591/2592/2593/2594/2595/2596/2597/2598/2599/2600/2601/2602/2603/2604/2605/2606/2607/2608/2609/2610/2611/2612/2613/2614/2615/2616/2617/2618/2619/2620/2621/2622/2623/2624/2625/2626/2627/2628/2629/2630/2631/2632/2633/2634/2635/2636/2637/2638/2639/2640/2641/2642/2643/2644/2645/2646/2647/2648/2649/2650/2651/2652/2653/2654/2655/2656/2657/2658/2659/2660/2661/2662/2663/2664/2665/2666/2667/2668/2669/2670/2671/2672/2673/2674/2675/2676/2677/2678/2679/2680/2681/2682/2683/2684/2685/2686/2687/2688/2689/2690/2691/2692/2693/2694/2695/2696/2697/2698/2699/2700/2701/2702/2703/2704/2705/2706/2707/2708/2709/2710/2711/2712/2713/2714/2715/2716/2717/2718/2719/2720/2721/2722/2723/2724/2725/2726/2727/..../9998/9999/10000/: File name too long
```

Can some one please let me know if there is some work around or do I have
to move into the 10000th folder by breaking the path and using multiple cd..

Comment: Can you please tell why do you want to do that?

Comment: I found that even on xfs and ext4 the file /usr/include/linux/limits.h mentions path length to be #define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */. I had a requirement to create a deep directory structure of 10,000 directories for testing from someone.

Comment: Any system that requires such a deeply nested directory seems to be broken by design.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I was asked to create such directory structure to test a software which takes backup of file system. Ofcourse this backup will fail since such a long path isn't supported. Should such a scenario be not tested, or suggestion to create such a huge directory structure in test case it itself wrong?

Comment: You're in a quite unfortunate situation. This blog post might shed some light: http://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2007/11/pathmax-simply-isnt.html (although I'm not sure if things have changed).